# Validate Number Column not to accept comma

Tags: column, validation, ootb

I want to use ootb column validation to not accept the comma in number field. Can anyone suggest to me what a formula would look like?

Comment: You can check PreSaveAction() for client side validation for NewForm.aspx for your list. Here's a link http://www.manvir.net/client-side-validation-in-sharepoint-new-and-edit-forms-using-presaveaction/

Comment: @RansherSingh thanks i had solved the problem from this.